# Change scan resolution permanently

Tags: scanner

I use Scangear for my scanning with a Canon MG 2220 printer/scanner.

It's default is set for 300 dpi which is more than I need.

Can I set it's default to 200 ?

I know you can change it under advanced but it goes back to 300 dpi after program is closed.

Thanks.

Comment: I wondered if you had tried xsane for scaning; sane shows complete support for the MG2200series devices; .. so it ... should .. work; xsane has many options; a very good programme;

Comment: Thanks pdc. I installed xsane and it does let me set the dpi setting. I could not figure out how to mark your reply as showing research effort. I am still getting use to all the features of this forum.

Comment: thanks; enjoy xsane; it has many, many options  and tweaks